# Laravel blade user editable HTML/Layout

Tags: laravel

I am looking for "best practice" or a package for users to be able to change layout / HTML. I understand that I need to have some kind of "template" language that is converted to blade in order not to risk "bad code". Grateful if you have any tips! :)

Comment: Blade is already a template language that is compiled to PHP, there really isn't a reason to go from some other language to Blade to PHP

Comment: yes i know that, i think you missed the point. I want users to be able to change the layout.

Comment: if this has anything to do with end users you could look into twig since it has sandboxing